# GraphQL Relay defaultValue for array of object in fragment argument definitions

Tags: graphql, relay

I am trying to define my createRefetchContainer with fragment. However, I am getting an error about defaultValue of array of object type. I checked the documentation yet I couldn't figure out how to handle default value attribute for array of object type parameter.

I tried to put empty array "**[]**" or "**[{ key: "status", value: "active" }]**" but none of them worked.

```
export default createRefetchContainer(
  translate('admin')(UserList),
  graphql`
    fragment UserList_usersWithPage on Query
      @argumentDefinitions(
        filters: { type: [UserFilterInput], defaultValue: [] }
        pageNumber: { type: Int, defaultValue: 0 }
        pageSize: { type: Int, defaultValue: 25 }
      ) {
      page: findUsersWithPage(filters: $filters, pageNumber: $pageNumber, pageSize: $pageSize) {
        totalPages
        totalElements
        users {
          ...MiniProfile_user @relay(mask: false)
        }
      }
    }

    fragment UserList_filterFields on Query {
      accounts: findDistinctUserAccounts
      departments: findDistinctUserDepartments
      expertises: findDistinctUserExpertises
      ranks: findAllUserRankCodes
    }
  `,
  graphql`
    query UserListRefetchQuery($userFilterInput: [UserFilterInput], $pageNumber: Int, $pageSize: Int) {
      ...UserList_usersWithPage
        @arguments(userFilterInput: $userFilterInput, pageNumber: $pageNumber, pageSize: $pageSize)
    }
  `,
);


ERROR:
GraphQLParser: Expected definition for variable `filters` to be an object 
with the following shape: `{type: string, defaultValue?: mixed, nonNull?: 
boolean, list?: boolean}`, got `[object Object]`. Source: document 
`UserList_usersWithPage` file: `scenes/admin/pages/UserList.js`.
```

Comment: Get rid of the brackets around `UserFilterInput`

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that appears to work by wrapping the full argument type in a string and flagging my array member type as required within the array using "!":

```js
...
@argumentDefinitions(
  filters: { type: "[Filter!]", defaultValue: [] }
)
...
```

So in OP's example, that'd mean:

```js
export default createRefetchContainer(
  translate('admin')(UserList),
  graphql`
    fragment UserList_usersWithPage on Query
      @argumentDefinitions(
        filters: { type: "[UserFilterInput!]", defaultValue: [] }
        pageNumber: { type: Int, defaultValue: 0 }
        pageSize: { type: Int, defaultValue: 25 }
      ) {
      ...
```

Note that an empty array is still a valid argument type, as `[Type!]` allows for empty arrays, but requires that any members be non-null of type `Type`.

I'm still pretty new to graphql and relay myself, so cannot go into more detail on *why* this is working at this time.